# Idiomatic way to handle request and asynchronous response in c++

Tags: c++, c++17

I am working on a project that requires me to make use of 3rd party library. This library has a api to make a request for some data and register a callback that will be called when data is available. To link a request to it's response a unique integer tag is returned when a request is placed and same tag is returned when callback is invoked. Following is a signature of request creation api and callback.

```
void make_request(RequestData& data, (*cb)(int tag, Message *msg, void* closure), void* closure, int& tag)
```

Here closure parameter is something that we can set when making a request and same is returned as one of the parameter to callback.

My questions are -

1. What is a standard way of handling this type of communication in c++ (I am using c++17).
2. What is a name for such type of design. I need to know it so that I can study more about  it.

Comment: So you have the integer tag that you could use as the key to a map and you also get an opaque pointer that can point to anything you want it to?  It's almost as if they have given you two different ways to do the exact same thing: you can either store the data in a map keyed on the tag or you can pass it in the closure... I guess the closure is better if you don't need to know how many requests are active or have access to the closure data from outside the response function - the only advantage to passing the data as the closure is that you don't need to control concurrent access to the map...

Comment: I don't know how complex your code gets, but coroutines (if you could bump up that version to C++20) in my opinion would be pretty useful here to avoid callback spaghetti.